# Untar with root: is it possible to set the uid?

Tags: root, tar, chef

Is it possible to tell tar to unpack the archive and set the uid/gid to a specific one, when you run tar as root (while using chef) ?

Things I already know:

- I can use `-o` to extract as root, then `chown uid:gid` afterwards
- `--owner` and `--group` apparently only work when adding file, not when unpacking

It would be really convenient to be able to specify the owner while unpacking. Is that possible ?

Answer (score 2):

Oddly enough, you can get closer to what you want using (GNU) `cpio` with your tar archive.  GNU `cpio` supports tar format files, and provides the `-R` command line option to set the user and group of extracted files.  This option controls the ownership of *all* files, not specific files.

All this means that you can run, as root, the following command...

```
cpio -iv -R user1:group1 < /path/to/myarchive.tar
```

...and it will extract all the files owned by user `user1` and group `group1`.

Answer (score 1):

You can run the chef execute resource as a particular user:

```
execute "tar -xf /path/to/your/tarfile.tar" do
  user "someone"
end
```

[Execute Resource Documentation](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Resources#Resources-Execute)